# hbase 2.5.6 Windows 10 Errors

Tags: database, windows, shell, bigdata, hbase

C:\hbase-2.5.6\bin>start-hbase.cmd

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactoryat org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:185)at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool.main(HBaseConfTool.java:36)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactoryat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)... 2 moreERROR: Could not determine the startup mode.
```

Comment: And your question is?